# The blending tool doubt in GIMP, please help solve this situation?

Tags: gimp

I am new to GIMP and have an image that is 700x400 in size. I want to add a text to this image, but not *on* the image. So I went ahead and created a little bit of space on the right side of the image and, created a new layer and filled the space with black color. Now, we have the image and then that black space on the right side of the image, where I am going to add text to.

My problem is:

I want to blend this black block to the image and appear it as a fading. So, what I did was I created a duplicate layer. Then using the gradient tool, I dragged from one side to the other. The color has given the effect of blend, but there's this problem. it's is not blending properly, I can still see the division between the black block to the right and the image, where I want them to blend, I want the black to fully blend to the image.

*How should I proceed?*

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you buddy. That worked well. Actually I was dragging it too much and from what you have taught me, the problem has been solved. Thanks. Just check out the image now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The Blend tool adds a gradient to the image - starting at one end of the line you draw to the other, and, for a simple foreground to transparent gradient-at least, from full transparency to full opacity (or vice versa).

So, for a quick transparency to foreground blend, you'd place the tool handles as follows:

[image: Blend tool on an empty canvas]

The tool position is approximate - I did the gradient first, then reused the tool to have it display its handles again for the screenshot).

The left handle marks the position where total transparency is reached, the right marks the begin of total opacity.

This should give you an idea of how this tool is used.